# Background worker RunWorkerCompleted is never fired

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

Using the following code my background worker `RunWorkerCompleted` is never called and I can't figure out why.

```
void startWaitScan()
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // do something here
}

void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted");
    if (!stopAsync)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

My goal is for the background worker to run continuously, I had this working in .NET but when I rewrote the code now in C# I'm having this issue.

Comment: What kind of App exactly?  This will only work in WinForms or WPF.

Comment: C# Windows Forms application

Comment: What's you `//Do something here`? are you sure it's not looping infinitely? Set a breakpoint inside the DoWork and check that it actually exits.

Comment: How is your `BackgroundWorker` declared?

Comment: Are you regestering the handler for complete?  backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

Comment: @Blam is right I didn't do that, I guess thats what i was missing

Comment: Thanks everyone @Blam and Rwiti were correct, I appreciate all the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you have all the events hooked up correctly ??

```
 backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
 backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
                                                 backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

Comment: You can do that in the constructor. 
usually its done in the InitializeComponent() method by the forms designer

Comment: Thank you that was it, I knew it was something stupid, Really appreciate the help

Comment: It did, I'll select this answer as correct in 5 minutes when it allows me to do so. Thanks again

Comment: Are these two lines equal to java applet's action-listeners and executors?

Comment: Action Listener in this case is backgroundWorker1_DoWork and backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted. Java executors are more [capable than executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)